# Circe generic codec derivation for records with object keys

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'm trying to implement something like

```
object Claims {
  import shapeless._
  import shapeless.labelled.FieldType
  import io.circe._
  import io.circe.generic.semiauto._
  import java.util.UUID

  type ClaimOf[V] = FieldOf[V]
  object iss extends ClaimOf[String]
  object subj extends ClaimOf[String]
  object aud extends ClaimOf[Set[String]]
  object client_id extends ClaimOf[UUID]

  implicit val encoder =
    deriveEncoder[FieldType[iss.type, String] :: FieldType[subj.type, String] :: HNil]
}
```

It does not compiles with an error
`error: could not find implicit value for parameter encode: shapeless.Lazy[io.circe.generic.encoding.DerivedObjectEncoder[shapeless.::[shapeless.labelled.FieldType[Claims.iss.type,String],shapeless.::[shapeless.labelled.FieldType[Claims.subj.type,String],shapeless.HNil]]]]
           deriveEncoder[FieldType[iss.type, String] :: FieldType[subj.type, String] :: HNil]`

Answer (score 3):

According to [Travis Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/334519/travis-brown) the problem is "The generic derivation is designed to work with Shapeless's generic instances and expects the FieldType key to be a symbol." [See discussion on Gitter](https://gitter.im/travisbrown/circe?at=56deff9a68ddef776469a33d).

My solution:

```
object Claims {
  import shapeless._
  import shapeless.labelled.FieldType
  import io.circe._
  import io.circe.syntax._
  import io.circe.generic.semiauto._
  import io.circe.generic.encoding.DerivedObjectEncoder
  import java.util.UUID

  abstract case class ClaimOf[V](name: String) extends FieldOf[V]

  object iss extends ClaimOf[String]("iss")
  object subj extends ClaimOf[String]("subj")
  object aud extends ClaimOf[Set[String]]("aud")
  object client_id extends ClaimOf[UUID]("client_id")

  implicit final def encodeClaims[K, H, T <: HList](implicit key: Witness.Aux[K],
                                                       claim: K <:< ClaimOf[H],
                                                       encodeHead: Lazy[Encoder[H]],
                                                       encodeTail: Lazy[DerivedObjectEncoder[T]]
                                                      ): DerivedObjectEncoder[FieldType[K, H] :: T] =
  new DerivedObjectEncoder[FieldType[K, H] :: T] {
    final def encodeObject(a: FieldType[K, H] :: T): JsonObject = a match {
      case h :: t =>
        (key.value.name -> encodeHead.value(h)) +: encodeTail.value.encodeObject(t)
    }
  }

  val encoder = deriveEncoder[FieldType[iss.type, String] :: FieldType[subj.type, String] :: HNil]

  val rec = (iss ->> "issuer") :: (subj ->> "subject") :: HNil

  val json = rec.asJson.spaces2
}
```

The `encodeClaims` function is basically a copy of the original function from `circe`, replacing constraint on the keys.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37011894/circe-instances-for-encoding-decoding-sealed-trait-instances-of-arity-0/37015184#37015184) can be used to implement another solution.