# Circe instances for encoding/decoding sealed trait instances of arity 0?

Tags: scala, circe

I'm using sealed traits as enums for exhaustive pattern matching.  In cases where I have case objects instead of case classes extending my trait, I'd like to encode and decode (via [Circe](http://circe.io)) as just a plain string.

For example:

```
sealed trait State
case object On extends State
case object Off extends State

val a: State = State.Off
a.asJson.noSpaces // trying for "Off"

decode[State]("On") // should be State.On
```

I understand that this will be configurable in 0.5.0, but can anyone help me write something to tide me over until that's released?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To highlight the problem—assuming this ADT:

```
sealed trait State
case object On extends State
case object Off extends State
```

circe's generic derivation will (currently) produce the following encodings:

```
scala> import io.circe.generic.auto._, io.circe.syntax._
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.syntax._

scala> On.asJson.noSpaces
res0: String = {}

scala> (On: State).asJson.noSpaces
res1: String = {"On":{}}
```

This is because the generic derivation mechanism is built on Shapeless's `LabelledGeneric`, which represents case objects as empty `HList`s. This will probably always be the default behavior, since it's clean, simple, and consistent, but it's not always what you want (as you note the [configuration options](https://meta.plasm.us/posts/2016/01/14/configuring-generic-derivation/) that are coming soon will support alternatives).

You can override this behavior by providing your own generic instances for case objects:

```
import io.circe.Encoder
import shapeless.{ Generic, HNil }

implicit def encodeCaseObject[A <: Product](implicit
  gen: Generic.Aux[A, HNil]
): Encoder[A] = Encoder[String].contramap[A](_.productPrefix)
```

This says, "if the generic representation of `A` is an empty `HList`, encode it as its name as a JSON string". And it works as we'd expect for case objects that are statically typed as themselves:

```
scala> On.asJson.noSpaces
res2: String = "On"
```

When the value is statically typed as the base type, the story is a little different:

```
scala> (On: State).asJson.noSpaces
res3: String = {"On":"On"}
```

We get a generically derived instance for `State`, and it respects our manually defined generic instance for case objects, but it still wraps them in an object. This makes some sense if you think about it—the ADT *could* contain case classes, which can only reasonably be represented as a JSON object, and so the object-wrapper-with-constructor-name-key approach is arguably the most reasonable thing to do.

It's not the only thing we can do, though, since we *do* know statically whether the ADT contains case classes or only case objects. First we need a new type class that witnesses that an ADT is made up only of case objects (note that I'm assuming a fresh start here, but it should be possible to make this work alongside generic derivation):

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.labelled.{ FieldType, field }

trait IsEnum[C <: Coproduct] {
  def to(c: C): String
  def from(s: String): Option[C]
}

object IsEnum {
  implicit val cnilIsEnum: IsEnum[CNil] = new IsEnum[CNil] {
    def to(c: CNil): String = sys.error("Impossible")
    def from(s: String): Option[CNil] = None
  }

  implicit def cconsIsEnum[K <: Symbol, H <: Product, T <: Coproduct](implicit
    witK: Witness.Aux[K],
    witH: Witness.Aux[H],
    gen: Generic.Aux[H, HNil],
    tie: IsEnum[T]
  ): IsEnum[FieldType[K, H] :+: T] = new IsEnum[FieldType[K, H] :+: T] {
    def to(c: FieldType[K, H] :+: T): String = c match {
      case Inl(h) => witK.value.name
      case Inr(t) => tie.to(t)
    }
    def from(s: String): Option[FieldType[K, H] :+: T] =
      if (s == witK.value.name) Some(Inl(field[K](witH.value)))
        else tie.from(s).map(Inr(_))
  }
}
```

And then our generic `Encoder` instances:

```
import io.circe.Encoder

implicit def encodeEnum[A, C <: Coproduct](implicit
  gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, C],
  rie: IsEnum[C]
): Encoder[A] = Encoder[String].contramap[A](a => rie.to(gen.to(a)))
```

Might as well go ahead and write the decoder too.

```
import cats.data.Xor, io.circe.Decoder

implicit def decodeEnum[A, C <: Coproduct](implicit
  gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, C],
  rie: IsEnum[C]
): Decoder[A] = Decoder[String].emap { s =>
  Xor.fromOption(rie.from(s).map(gen.from), "enum")
}
```

And then:

```
scala> import io.circe.jawn.decode
import io.circe.jawn.decode

scala> import io.circe.syntax._
import io.circe.syntax._

scala> (On: State).asJson.noSpaces
res0: String = "On"

scala> (Off: State).asJson.noSpaces
res1: String = "Off"

scala> decode[State](""""On"""")
res2: cats.data.Xor[io.circe.Error,State] = Right(On)

scala> decode[State](""""Off"""")
res3: cats.data.Xor[io.circe.Error,State] = Right(Off)
```

Which is what we wanted.

Comment: It turns out this breaks down when the sealed trait is contained within an object.  I have been experimenting, but I would love some guidance on figuring out a way to approach this issue.