# How to encode Json when HList parameter is HNil?

Tags: scala, shapeless, circe

Having this example,

```
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.shapes._
import io.circe.parser._
import io.circe.syntax._
import shapeless._

case class A[T <: HList](name: String, params: T)
```

when I instance this case class with a non-empty HList, there is no problem:

```
scala> A("name", "a" :: HNil).asJson
res1: io.circe.Json =
{
  "name" : "name",
  "params" : [
    "a"
  ]
}
```

But, when this HList is only HNil, I get the follow error:

```
scala> A("name", HNil).asJson
<console>:29: error: could not find implicit value for parameter encoder: io.circe.Encoder[A[shapeless.HNil.type]]
   A("name", HNil).asJson
                   ^
```

I've read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37011894/circe-instances-for-encoding-decoding-sealed-trait-instances-of-arity-0) where they talk about case object encoder, but it doesn't work with HNil (HNil is case object) and I've seen anything about it in the documentation. FYI, I'm using circe 0.6.1

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to the fact that the static type of `HNil` is more specific than `HNil` (i.e. it's `HNil.type`). The following will work as expected:

```
scala> A("name", HNil: HNil).asJson.noSpaces
res0: String = {"name":"name","params":{}}
```

We *could* provide `Encoder` and `Decoder` instances for `HNil.type`, but in general when you construct a type with `HNil` and `::` the static type of the `HNil` is `HNil`, and to keep things simple we decide to provide instances only for `HNil`.

This issue comes up in other places, including in Shapeless itself, where a search for `HNil: HNil` returns thirty-something occurrences.

Comment: Here's an example of what the might look like: https://github.com/eed3si9n/sjson-new/blob/899686e4a3778dfbf16b745befc31a84d6c53fb3/support/scalajson/src/test/scala/sjsonnew/support/scalajson/unsafe/HList.scala#L29-L42

Answer (score 2):

Travis' answer is valid, you can certainly encode `HNil` by using a type annotation. I do not have enough reputation so I can't comment his answer, but I noticed that non-empty `HList`s encode as JSON arrays, while an empty `Hlist` is encoded as an empty JSON object.

Here's a quick code sample of this behavior.

```
@ (1 :: 2 :: "foo" :: HNil).asJson.noSpaces 
res1: String = """[1,2,"foo"]"""
@ (HNil: HNil).asJson.noSpaces 
res12: String = "{}"
```

Comment: Yeah, this is a kind of unfortunate inconsistency. Hlists can be encoded as either arrays or objects depending on whether they're labeled or not, but since an `HNil` is neither labeled nor unlabeled we have to choose one, and since `Unit` is encoded as `{}` (among other reasons), we go with the empty object.